# Remove control from Form: space is still occupied

Tags: winforms, toggle, richtextbox

I have a Form and want to toggle show and hide the `RichTextBox`.
If I hide the control, the control should give up the space reservation, but actually it doesn't.

it is Removed, but the original space reserved by `rtbcontrol` is still visible as empty grey space.
It seems, it affects only the Controls, which are anchored to the bottom.

I made a small sample for demonstrating my problem:
Desinger:

```
namespace HideShowTest
{
    partial class Form1
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Erforderliche Designervariable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Verwendete Ressourcen bereinigen.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">True, wenn verwaltete Ressourcen gelöscht werden sollen; andernfalls False.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Vom Windows Form-Designer generierter Code

        /// <summary>
        /// Erforderliche Methode für die Designerunterstützung.
        /// Der Inhalt der Methode darf nicht mit dem Code-Editor geändert werden.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.richTextBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox();
            this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.button2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.button3 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // richTextBox1
            // 
            this.richTextBox1.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)(((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left)
                        | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
            this.richTextBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(13, 126);
            this.richTextBox1.Name = "richTextBox1";
            this.richTextBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(289, 80);
            this.richTextBox1.TabIndex = 0;
            this.richTextBox1.Text = "";
            // 
            // button1
            // 
            this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(13, 13);
            this.button1.Name = "button1";
            this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(92, 23);
            this.button1.TabIndex = 3;
            this.button1.Text = "top anchor";
            this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            // 
            // button2
            // 
            this.button2.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left)));
            this.button2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(13, 75);
            this.button2.Name = "button2";
            this.button2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(92, 23);
            this.button2.TabIndex = 2;
            this.button2.Text = "bottom anchor";
            this.button2.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            // 
            // button3
            // 
            this.button3.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
            this.button3.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(227, 75);
            this.button3.Name = "button3";
            this.button3.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
            this.button3.TabIndex = 1;
            this.button3.Text = "Hide Rtb";
            this.button3.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.button3.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button3_Click);
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(314, 226);
            this.Controls.Add(this.button1);
            this.Controls.Add(this.button2);
            this.Controls.Add(this.button3);
            this.Controls.Add(this.richTextBox1);
            this.Name = "Form1";
            this.Text = "Form1";
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }

        #endregion

        private System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox richTextBox1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button button3;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button button2;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button button1;
    }
}
```

and Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace HideShowTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (richTextBox1.Visible)
            {
                richTextBox1.Hide();

                this.Height -= richTextBox1.Height;
            }
            else
            {
                richTextBox1.Show();

                this.Height += richTextBox1.Height;
            }
            button3.Text = richTextBox1.Visible ? "Hide Rtb" : "Show Rtb";
        }
    }
}
```

If I click "Hide Rtb", the bottom anchor button wanders up (it should stay at the same place).

Comment: The repro code has an obvious bug, the Anchor property of button2 and button3 is not correct.  Being anchored to the bottom, reducing the size of the from will move them from Y=75 to Y=-5.  Of course you don't want them there.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**: since you edited the question and asked about a totally different thing:

You have the `Anchor` property of button2 set to Left and **Bottom**, so it's clearly going to move when you resize the form in order to maintain the same distance between the button and the bottom of the form.

To avoid that, you can either set the `Anchor` property to Top or change the location of the button accordingly when changing the size of the form. For example:

```
int t = button2.Top;
ToggleRtbVisibility();
button2.Top = t;
```

---

**Original answer**:

1) If you want to toggle "show and hide", do hide and show the control, do not remove it.

2) I suspect that you checked the [`Size`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/25w4thew(v=vs.110).aspx) property of the form instead of the [`ClientSize`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9278sfx2(v=vs.110).aspx) property, but you're changing the value of the `ClientSize`. Also, don't use fixed numbers for changing the size, calculate them instead.

Try something like this:

```
private void ToggleRtbVisibility(bool hide)
{
    rtbLog.Visible = !hide;
    int preservedHeight = rtbLog.Height + rtbLog.Margin.Top + rtbLog.Margin.Bottom;
    if (hide)
    {
        this.Height -= preservedHeight;
    }
    else
    {
        this.Height += preservedHeight;
    }
}
```

And if you don't want use a parameter to explicitly specify whether to show or hide the control, you can change the above method to something like:

```
private void ToggleRtbVisibility()
{
    rtbLog.Visible = !rtbLog.Visible;
    int preservedHeight = rtbLog.Height + rtbLog.Margin.Top + rtbLog.Margin.Bottom;
    if (rtbLog.Visible == false)
        this.Height -= preservedHeight;
    else
        this.Height += preservedHeight;
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you Ahmed, it was not so easy to describe the problem: I made a sample (above), which should demonstrate that issue.

Comment: Please remove the answer above (since it's not an answer) and add the relevant information [into your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50131186/edit).

Comment: Also, this seems to be a different question. Is your _original problem_ solved?